# Bootstrap Navbar: width of parent-entity <a> retains natural width of scaled down child-img

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, width

Instead of displaying the brand in the navbar as text I included the img of the brand-logo which I scaled down for responsive reasons with "max-width 50%". the parent of the img is a hyperlink tag . the issue: the width of a remains displaying the original width of 100% of the img (being 350px instead of 50% of 350px). I have not been able to find a solution and kindly ask for your help.

```
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="background-color: black;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="max-width: 50%;">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: when you set a "max-width: 50%" on the element you set the max-width of this element to be 50% of a width of its parent (in current situation it's anchor element). So if your anchor has width explicitly set to 350px, only then your image will be 50% of 350px

Comment: thank you! To be sure: the img element already is displaying as 50% of 350px = 175px. but the parent element - instead of having a width of 175px like the img - is having a width of 350px. Does this change the comment above?

Comment: to be clear, I didn't answer your question on how to make your page responsive, I just pointed out what you were doing wrong: misusing the concept of percents in css. So to sum up: if your parent has fixed width, and its child has a width set to 50%, then your child will always be half the width of its parent.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to give me feedback! I am afraid that I am still not understanding: let me explain why - the parent does not have a fixed width. therefore shouldn't the parent adjust to the width of the child (no matter if I used the percents correctly or not?)

Comment: please do a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/, otherwise it's hard to understand the situation